# SPD 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have a "Team members" multiple person field that triggers an email to the people within the field. I do this by: If field is not empty send email.

My question is... If the project manager adds a new member to the currect list, how do I get the workflow to only send to the new member and not the existing members?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Julie

Answer (score 2):

First Nice question...got me thinking and would like other members to post their approach....
What I can think of now is to have a different field (call it New Members) on the form where new users needs to be added. Once the members are added there... workflow email triggers to these new members and in next step of workflow, add the member from this new field to the Team members field. In this way we can have the new users added to the Team Member field and at the same time email only to the new users.

I am sure there is lot better approach for this and I am looking forward for experts to reply.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought of this also but can't seem to figure out how to move the New Member to the Team Member. If you can shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We have Update Item action in SharePoint Designer.Check that.